# Keyboard shortcut for 'add 1 to URL' in firefox

Tags: xubuntu, firefox, shortcut-keys, scripts, firefox-extensions

I'm not sure where the best place is to ask this.

In Firefox, you can add bookmarks with the 'urls' of

javascript:(function(){%20var%20e,s;%20IB=1;%20function%20isDigit(c)%20{%20return%20("0"%20<=%20c%20&&%20c%20<=%20"9")%20}%20L%20=%20location.href;%20LL%20=%20L.length;%20for%20(e=LL-1;%20e>=0;%20--e)%20if%20(isDigit(L.charAt(e)))%20{%20for(s=e-1;%20s>=0;%20--s)%20if%20(!isDigit(L.charAt(s)))%20break;%20break;%20}%20++s;%20if%20(e<0)%20return;%20oldNum%20=%20L.substring(s,e+1);%20newNum%20=%20""%20+%20(parseInt(oldNum,10)%20+%20IB);%20while%20(newNum.length%20<%20oldNum.length)%20newNum%20=%20"0"%20+%20newNum;%20location.href%20=%20L.substring(0,s)%20+%20newNum%20+%20L.slice(e+1);%20})();

and

javascript:(function(){%20var%20e,s;%20IB=-1;%20function%20isDigit(c)%20{%20return%20("0"%20<=%20c%20&&%20c%20<=%20"9")%20}%20L%20=%20location.href;%20LL%20=%20L.length;%20for%20(e=LL-1;%20e>=0;%20--e)%20if%20(isDigit(L.charAt(e)))%20{%20for(s=e-1;%20s>=0;%20--s)%20if%20(!isDigit(L.charAt(s)))%20break;%20break;%20}%20++s;%20if%20(e<0)%20return;%20oldNum%20=%20L.substring(s,e+1);%20newNum%20=%20""%20+%20(parseInt(oldNum,10)%20+%20IB);%20while%20(newNum.length%20<%20oldNum.length)%20newNum%20=%20"0"%20+%20newNum;%20location.href%20=%20L.substring(0,s)%20+%20newNum%20+%20L.slice(e+1);%20})();

which, if you put them in the bookmarks toolbar, they will make numerically sequential pages go up or down (respectively) by 1. I have them named "+" and "-" respectively.

I'd like to assign a keyboard shortcut to them but I can't work out how. Pasting those commands into Keyboard > Application Shortcuts (xubuntu) doesn't work because they're too long and I guess there's a length limit. Also I don't know that xubuntu knows to pass them to firefox so I guess I need to add something in front, maybe just "-firefox"?

But since it's too long, could I make a script do this? Maybe by using whatever the correct code should be above, then putting in ~/bin and making executable like [this](http://makandracards.com/makandra/12447-how-to-move-a-window-to-the-next-monitor-on-xfce-xubuntu)?

Thanks in advance for any tips/pointers. I guess this could also be used to make a keyboard shortcut for DownloadThemAll addon, which could do with one.

Comment: xdg-open might be the answer, from here: https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/266988/shell-script-to-open-a-web-page-in-mozilla-firefox .Edit: nope: says "bash: !isDigit: event not found".

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround which isn't a direct solution but does solve my problem:

[This](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/bookmark-shortcut-keys/) firefox addon allows you to use ctrl+1 ctrl+2 etc for hotkey bookmarks. Can change ctrl to alt or whatever but not the 1-9. Does the job.